# How to get value of KProperty1

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

[I have an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJYKi.png)

I try to get access to field "english"

```
val englishSentence = dbField::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter { it.name == "english" }[0]
```

But when I

```
model.addAttribute("sentence", englishSentence)
```

I get ***val com.cyrillihotin.grammartrainer.entity.Sentence.english: kotlin.String***

while I expect ***bla***

Comment: What is `dbField`? A data class?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes, https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJYKi.png

Comment: Prefer adding code as text in the question, instead of sending image urls.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I thought image is more clear and beautiful

Comment: @Kokoro See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for many reasons to prefer text over images of code/data/errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `call` function on a `KProperty` to get its value from the object.

```kotlin
val dbField = Sentence(1, "bla-eng", "bla-rus")
val value = dbField::class.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "english" }!!.call(dbField)
println(value)
```

Output: `bla-eng`

Remember that data type of `value` is `Any` here. You need to cast it manually to the desired data type.

If you want to list all the properties with their values, you can do this:

```
dbField::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
    println("${it.name} -> ${it.call(dbField)}")
}
```

Output:

```
english -> bla-eng
id -> 1
russian -> bla-rus
```

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
data class Sentence(val id:Int, val english:String, val russian:String)
val dbField = Sentence(1, "blaEng", "blaRus")
val englishProp = dbField::class.declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == "english" }as KProperty1<Sentence, String>
println(englishProp.get(dbField))
```

It prints `blaEng`